# SNAPSHOT-development jar overwritten by snapshot build

Tags: maven, unit-testing, snapshot

I use the following command to run test:

mvn test -Dtest=CTest -DtestDataFile=xx -s settings.xml

Before running the above, I copied custom built jar to ~/.m2/repository/x/y/z:

369588 Mar 11 20:47 SNAPSHOT-development.jar

After running the above, I got (same path):

369556 Mar 11 20:07 SNAPSHOT-development.jar

I wonder how I can disable mvn downloading the snapshot jar.
(In Intellij, "Always update snapshots" can be toggled)

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T11:41:47-07:00)
Maven home: /Users/yute/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre

Answer (score 0):

In the `settings.xml` under the repositories tag, you can set an update policy. The standard is "daily", which means that the SNAPSHOT is downloaded once a day.

You can disable the download by setting the policy to "never".

Comment: There is one repositories tag under jdk-1.4 profile in settings.xml but I don't think the profile is used. Can I disable the download for mirrors tag ?      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>

Comment: So where does your Snapshot come from? Where is the repository defined?

Comment: The snapshot comes from company internal artifactory

Comment: So, this artifactory should be in the `settings.xml`. Or is it defined in the POM?

Comment: Added the policy for <snapshots> in the pom.xml but the dev jar is still overwritten:        <repository>
<snapshots>
<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
</snapshots>
            <id>maven2</id>